# Attaching and detaching databases in Management Studio does not result in unloading old database and loading the new one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have two versions of the same database, say `DB1` and `DB2`. DB1 is a copy made of the mdb and the log file a month ago. The database structure and data has changed since then. I need to switch back and forth between these two copies in SQL Server Management Studio.

The structure of the `Customer` table in these versions is different. So it is easy to see which version is loaded in Management Studio.

I detach `DB1` and attach `DB2` and do `select * on Customer` and see the structure still belonging to `DB1`. How do I switch to `DB2` properly?

I am using the right `use DB` statement and have the right db selcted in the dropdown on the left hand side for selecting databases.

Comment: @marc_s, they are copies of the same database saved at different times. They had the same name. i changed the file names. this is somehow creating a conflict.

Comment: Make sure the filenames of the db and log are different on the copy.

Comment: I create a copy of a production database for test on the same server often.  It should work.  You can copy or backup-restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow Management studio was caching the location of the file.  When attaching the database, I had to go to the "current file path", and edit the wrong path and point to the right one. This had to be done even when after clicking the add button I had already chosen the right mdb file with the right path.

Answer (score 0):

The drop-down at the top controls which DB you are using, if the DBs are on the same instance of SQL Server. If they are different instances, use the "change connection" button at the top left, then pick your DB from the drop-down.